# Design matrix of a model

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, linear-regression

Suppose we have a model $y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} x_{i1} + \beta_{2}x_{i2} + \epsilon_{i}$. Then I need to find a general expression for  $\hat{\sigma}²(X^TX)^{-1}$.

My first thought was that we have a $3$x$3$ matrix. So simply compute the following:

$X^TX=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & 1\\
x_1 &  \dots & x_1\\
x_2 & \dots & x_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_1 & x_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
n & \sum x_i & \sum x_{j+1}\\
\sum x_i & \sum x_i^2 & \sum x_i x_{j+1} \\
\sum x_{j+1} & \sum x_{j+1} x_i & \sum x_{j+1}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}_{i=j=1}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
n & n\overline{x_1} & n \overline{x}_2\\
n \overline{x}_1 & \sum x_i^2 & n \overline{x}_1\overline{x}_2 \\
n \overline{x}_2 & n \overline{x}_2 x_1 & \sum x^2_{j+1}
\end{pmatrix}_{i=j=1}
$.

Then take the inverse with a very messy determinant. Is this the correct approach or is there any simpler/easier way to do this?

Comment: You have general formulas for the inverse of a 3x3 matrix, but of course it will be ugly whatever you do.  (Note : what guarantees that this matrix is indeed invertible ?). However usually for solving the normal equations for linear regression you prefer using QR factorization.

Comment: Using double index for the design matrix seems useful to me.  $$\textbf X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_{11} & x_{12}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{n1} & x_{n2} \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. Btw. is there any general form for $\hat{\sigma}^2$ in this case?